# Need some suggestion to buys books of javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

May be this question duplicate or redundant but i want to elaborate my question so:

**i have tried looking to google and flipkar,amazon that ...but by just looking at the book you can't really judge how it will be...and it's always good ask someone who has experience...because i can't keep on buying to find good book**

I want to buy books on jquery and javascript,and please consider that i am not a experienced in javascript and jquery neither a beginner ...so i want buy a book that has a very high level ....so that all goes above my head...

if some **experienced** one can reply to this it will be helpfull...and all others(less experienced) are also welcome.....

Hoping i will get good answer :)

Comment: All on this page http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do

Comment: You could try http://www.flipkart.com/computers-internet-books-1298?ref=d4f3db34-602e-4383-be5e-6ed9f72dd1e1.

Comment: @kidmenot of course i have tried that ...but by just looking at the book you can't really judge how it will be...and it's always good ask someone who has experience...because i can't keep on buying to find good book

Comment: you can't just browse the web and find books that have sold a large amount of copies and buy that one ? .. the comments/answers start looking promotional ..

Comment: @GeoPhoenix have u read my whole question and explanation....and i don't understand the logic to buy that has larger sale

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Good JavaScript Books?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/74884/851432)

Comment: @Jomoos yes i think all of you who has suggested ...is this book more..i will with this...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First book to become JS developer is

[JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

I love this book as well

[Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/): has very basics of JS and best for that

if you want to test your perfection there is a way...

[A Test-Driven JS Assessment](https://github.com/rmurphey/js-assessment): A set of failing tests that cover various JavaScript topics; can you write code to make the tests pass?

[10 things I learned from the jQuery Source](http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/) will help you understand how to dismantle others JS scripts perfectly

Comment: thanks and i think am gonna to buy first one u suggested

Comment: are you expecting more information?

Comment: no this is quite good u have provided...but i didn't understand why do people think of promotional or what..i just wanted refernce...anyways still  i got some good reference :)